# DocumentReference.update() not working when app is being killed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update my firestore database when a fragment is destroyed.

When I replace my fragment A by another one (within an Activity), A.onDestroy() is called and DocumentRefence.update() works perfectly.

The problem is, I got a strange behavior when I perform an update, **in the case where Fragment.onDestroy() is called when the app is being closed by the user.** (When the user swipe out the app in recent apps)

It looks like the method DocumentReference.update() doesn't run and just block my code.

Here is onDestroy() in my Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("Fragment", "onDestroy: before");
    FirestoreHelper.removePlayer(viewModel.getGameName(), viewModel.getPlayerName());
    Log.d("Fragment", "onDestroy: after");

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And here the method which update the DocumentReference.

```
public static void removePlayer(String gameName, String playerName) {
        Log.d("Firestore", "removePlayer: before");
        DocumentReference docRef = getGamesReference().document(gameName);
        Log.d("Firestore", "removePlayer: middle");
        docRef.update("players." + playerName, FieldValue.delete());
        Log.d("Firestore", "removePlayer: after");
    }
```

Here's my log after I close the app :

```
D/Activity: onDestroy: 
D/Fragment: onDestroy: before
D/Firestore: removePlayer: before
D/Firestore: removePlayer: middle
```

You can see that docRef.update(...) blocks the code.

Thanks in advance for any answer !

Comment: On Android, when the user removes the app from the task list, that kills the app process entirely.  It can't continue to execute code.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy%28%29), there is no guarantee that the onDestroy() will ever be called. As mentioned by @Doug Stevenson in the comment, once the user removes the app from the task list, it will no longer run the code.